# Cambiar color de fila de DataTables dependiendo un valor

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, php7, php5

Tengo el siguiente código:

**JS:**

```
function declararDataTable()
{
    var id_temporada = $("#id_temporadaVal").val();
    var id_equipo = $("#id_equipoVal").val();   

    tabla_jugadores = $('#jugadores').dataTable({
        "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ jugadores por página",
                "sZeroRecords": "No existen jugadores",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ jugadores",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 a 0 de 0 jugadores",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Encontrados de _MAX_ jugadores)"
        },
        "aoColumns": [{"sWidth":"20%"},{"sWidth":"10%"},{"sWidth":"10%"}],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../includes/acciones/compilacion/get_jugadores_equipos_json.php',
        "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "id_temporada", "value": id_temporada });
            aoData.push({ "name": "id_equipo", "value": id_equipo });
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 25
    });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
include_once("../../clases/class.Jugador.php");

extract($_GET);
# id_temporada
# id_equipo

$jugadores = Jugador::getLista($id_equipo, $id_temporada);

$json = array();

if(is_array($jugadores))
{
    foreach($jugadores as $jugador)
    {
        $temp = array();
        array_push($temp, $jugador["nombre"]." ".$jugador['apellido_paterno']." ".$jugador["apellido_materno"]);    
        $link = "<a href='javascript:visuaModal(".$jugador['id_jugador'].");'>
         <img src='../img/editar.png' width='30' height='30'></a>";
        array_push($temp, $link);
        $link2 = "<a href='javascript:bajas(".$jugador['id_jugador'].");'>
         <img src='../img/eliminar.png' width='30' height='30'></a>";       
        array_push($temp, $link2);
        array_push($json, $temp);
    }
}

echo json_encode(array("aaData" => $json));
?>
```

Explico con la función JavaScript `declararDataTable` lo que hago es mandar a **php** ciertos parámetros con los cuales voy a obtener la información a mostrar en la DataTable, esa misma función recibe de **php** un **JSON** el cual contiene la información a imprimir en el DataTable, el inconveniente que estoy teniendo es que necesito pintar las filas pero esto va a depender de un valor, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
 foreach($jugadores as $jugador)
 {
    $temp = array();

    $no_equipos = Jugador::getTotalEquipos($jugador['id_jugador'], $id_temporada);

    if($no_equipos == 2)
      // Se pintaria la fila a color amarillo
    else
     // La fila no se pinta

    array_push($temp, $jugador["nombre"]." ".$jugador['apellido_paterno']." ".$jugador["apellido_materno"]);    
    $link = "<a href='javascript:visuaModal(".$jugador['id_jugador'].");'>
         <img src='../img/editar.png' width='30' height='30'></a>";
    array_push($temp, $link);
    $link2 = "<a href='javascript:bajas(".$jugador['id_jugador'].");'>
         <img src='../img/eliminar.png' width='30' height='30'></a>";       
    array_push($temp, $link2);
    array_push($json, $temp);
 }
?>
```

Como podría resolver esto??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo añadiendo una variable `style` y a ella le añades un `background-color` de modo que por defecto sea `transparent`.

```php
<?php
 foreach($jugadores as $jugador)
 {
    $temp = array();

    $no_equipos = Jugador::getTotalEquipos($jugador['id_jugador'], $id_temporada);
    $style = "style=background-color:transparent";

    if($no_equipos == 2)
      $style = "style=background-color:yellow";
    else
     $style = "style=display:none";

    array_push($temp, "<p $style>$jugador['nombre'] $jugador['apellido_paterno'] $jugador['apellido_materno']</p>");    
    $link = "<a href='javascript:visuaModal(".$jugador['id_jugador'].");'>
         <img src='../img/editar.png' width='30' height='30'></a>";
    array_push($temp, $link);
    $link2 = "<a href='javascript:bajas(".$jugador['id_jugador'].");'>
         <img src='../img/eliminar.png' width='30' height='30'></a>";       
    array_push($temp, $link2);
    array_push($json, $temp);
 }
?>
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Comment: Y si quiero que se pinte la celda en donde se va a mostrar el nombre?? Porque en tu ejemplo añades color de fondo pero a los enlaces

Comment: Prueba ahora :)

Comment: Justamente antes de ver tu modificación, lo pensé así pero en lugar de un párrafo use un span

Comment: Genial, mira la sintaxis que utilicé para evitar que concatenar varios strings. Además es buena práctica de programación que el texto esté entre etiquetas `<p></p>`. Un saludo, me alegro de haberte ayudado.